# jQuery Autocomplete extra parameter not working

Tags: jquery, vb.net, autocomplete

Hi I want to use AutoComplete with VB.Net I am sick to find proper document and example. Please let me know what is wrong in my code ???? Thanks in advance.

(Autocomplete location based on stateid )

### Javascript

```
 $(function() {
        $("#Location").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "webservice/AutoComplete.asmx/GetLocations",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {                           
                        sid: $("#State").val(),
                        term: request.term
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        response($.map(data, function(item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.value,
                                value: item.value
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $('#Location').val(ui.item.label);
                $('#LocationID').val(ui.item.value);
            },
            open: function() {
                $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
            },
            close: function() {
                $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
            }
        });
    });
```

### Web Service (.asmx)

```
 Imports System.Web.Services
 Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
 Imports System.ComponentModel
 Imports System.Web.Script.Services
 Imports System.Web.Configuration
 Imports System.Data.SqlClient
 Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
 ' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
 <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
 <System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://xyz/webservice/")> _
 <System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
 <ToolboxItem(False)> _
 Public Class AutoComplete
     Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService
     Dim _objJavaScriptSerializer As JavaScriptSerializer
     Public Class Location
         Public value As String
         Public text As String
         Public location As String
         Public state As String
         Public country As String
         Public postcode As String
    End Class

   <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
   <WebMethod()> _
   Public Function GetLocations(ByVal term As String, ByVal sid As String) As String
       Dim _varConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings("CommonDBConnectionStringValue").ToString()).ToString()
      Dim _objSqlConnection As New SqlConnection(_varConnectionString)
      Dim _objSqlCommand As New SqlCommand("locations", _objSqlConnection)
      _objSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StateID", "3")
      _objSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchTerm", term)
      _objSqlCommand.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
      _objSqlConnection.Open()
      Dim _objSqlDataReader As SqlDataReader = _objSqlCommand.ExecuteReader
      Dim outputArray As New ArrayList
      While _objSqlDataReader.Read
          Dim _objLocations As New Location()
          _objLocations.value = _objSqlDataReader("LOCATIONID").ToString()
          _objLocations.text = _objSqlDataReader("LOCATION").ToString() & " " & _objSqlDataReader("STATECODE").ToString() & " " & _objSqlDataReader("POSTCODE").ToString() & " " & _objSqlDataReader("COUNTRYCODE").ToString()
         _objLocations.location = _objSqlDataReader("LOCATION").ToString()
         _objLocations.state = _objSqlDataReader("STATECODE").ToString()
         _objLocations.country = _objSqlDataReader("COUNTRYCODE").ToString()
         _objLocations.postcode = _objSqlDataReader("POSTCODE").ToString()
         outputArray.Add(_objLocations)
      End While
      _objSqlConnection.Close()
      _objJavaScriptSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()
      Return _objJavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(outputArray)
    End Function
 End Class
```

### WebService Returned Data

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
   <string xmlns="http://xyz/webservice/">
        [{"value":"44","text":"Brisbane QLD 4000 AUS","location":"Brisbane","state":"QLD","country":"AUS","postcode":"4000"}]
   </string>
```

Please help me out what is wrong in this code :((

Answer (score 0):

The `select` option of the call to autocomplete() is looking for a *label* property in the returned JSON

```
$('#Location').val(ui.item.label);
```

but it doesn't exist. I would try renaming the `text` (or whatever you want showing) property to `label`.